# Does $HK$ being a subgroup imply $H \subset N_G(K)$

Tags: group-theory

The converse is true. I feel this is false, but can't think of a counter-example.

Comment: Explain your notation

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I follow standard notation from most algebra textbooks (e.g. Dummit and Foote) where $N_G(K)$ is normalizer of subgroup $K$ in $G$, $H,K$ are both subgroups and $HK$ is $\{hk, \forall h \in H, \forall k \in K\}$

Comment: $G=S_3$, $H=\langle (123)\rangle$, $K=\langle (12)\rangle$.

Comment: Clearly if $H=G,HK=G$ is a trivial subgroup of $G$ but $G\not\subset N_G(K)$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: People don't call $G$ "a trivial subgroup of $G$" unless $G$ is trivial (the trivial subgroup is $\{e\}$). You presumably meant "trivially a subgroup"; and of course, $G\not\subseteq N_G(K)$ only holds if you also assume $K$ is not normal in $G$. By the way, the notation is *entirely* standard.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the correction. Yes, I meant to say 'trivially a subgroup'. The question mentions $\subset$ and not $\subseteq$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: Treating $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ as different is not rare, but also not entirely common. If that was your question, you could have asked if he meant proper inclusion or simple inclusion, rather than **ordering** him to explain his notation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't see why you're making fuss out of me asking him to explain his notation. I didn't accuse the notation of being non-standard. It was just not immediately recognizable to me.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: Because you didn't **ask**, you *ordered him* to explain it. When you ask, you say things like "Could you explain your notation?" Your phrasing is that of one person ordering another to do so something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you do not need that.

For example, in $S_3$, $H=\langle (123)\rangle$, $K=\langle (12)\rangle$; then $HK = S_3$ is a group, but $N_{S_3}(K) = K$.

Of course, in this case you do have $K\subseteq N_G(H)$, but even that is not necessary; that is, you can have $HK=KH$ as sets, $H\not\subset N_G(K)$, and $K\not\subset N_G(H)$.

For example, take $G=S_4$, and let $H$ be the dihedral group of order $8$ embedded in $G$ as $\langle (1234),(24)\rangle$, and $K=\langle (123)\rangle$. It is easy to verify via the usual counting formula that $|HK|=|KH|=24$, and hence $HK=KH=S_4$, but neither $H$ normalizes $K$ nor $K$ normalizes $H$.